# How to change the appearance of a row within a DataGrid, based on the value of a cell, in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

As I'm new in C# WPF, I tried to give it a go, using the trial-and-error approach.

What I would like to do, is to change the appearance of a row in a `DataGrid`, based on some user action.
However, from reading information over the internet, I've understood that the "right" way to go is:

> You should not write a method or a function: you need to write an event.

Okay, okay, so I started doing this in the XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_Areas" ... LoadingRow="View_dg_Areas"/>
```

Apparently, the `View_dg_Areas` event handler should have following signature:

```
private void View_dg_Areas(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) { }
```

But then what?

I started, very naïvely, as follows:

```
private void View_dg_Areas(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Row.ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Row.Item.ToString());
}
```

The idea was to learn from this how I can find information of the corresponding row (is there a way to read the value of a certain column?), but I didn't get anywhere.

I can tell you that the `DataGrid` is linked to a `DataTable`, as follows:

```
dg_Areas.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables["Areas"].DefaultView;
```

How can I link the event parameter `e` and the `DataTable` the `DataGrid` is representing?

Comment: The event would not be `LoadingRow` but whatever event the user triggered, for example, button_Click

Comment: In the DataGrid events, and in most control events, the sender is the DataGrid in which the event happened. So inside the method `View_dg_Areas(object sender,` you could do a direct cast similar to: `DataGrid grid = (DataGrid) sender`. But if only one grid used that function you could just access the grid `dg_Areas`

Comment: @Cleptus: I have some experience in GUI programming, so I know about the `sender` object. The background idea of my question is to learn about `DataGridRowEventArgs`. Can you give an example of its usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `RowStyle` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to one of your properties or columns:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_Areas">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourColumn}" Value="SomeValue">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

The above sample markup changes the background colour of the rows where "YourColumn" equals "SomeValue".

Using XAML defined styles to change the visual appearance is considered a best practice. Handling events is not.

Comment: My final goal is to highlight and modify tupples in a DataGrid when items in another DataGrid are selected (based on `ForeignKeyConstraints`), so I must work with events. This question is just a first step towards my final goal: first highlight a row, based on a value. Later on, highlight a row, based on another GUI event.